# Anyway to get the picklist back in gedit?

Tags: 20.04, gedit

Upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04, and the missing picklist in gedit is increasingly frustrating. By "picklist" I mean the dropdown menu where you could go to any of your open documents.

This picklist is replaced with some `<` `>` arrows, so instead of just opening the picklist and choosing the document, you have to click and click and click forwards or backwards.

There *must* be a tweak to get the picklist back :)